# packrat fails to retrieve Bioconductor packages

Tags: r, bioconductor, packrat

I'm trying to use packrat to get some semblance of reproducibility from different R projects. However it consistently fails to fetch Bioconductor packages when restoring from a snapshot. curl returns a 404 as it tries to fetch them from CRAN even though the `packrat.lock` file indicates the pkg source is Bioc, and BiocManager is installed and loaded in the packrat dir. For example:

```
Package: BiocGenerics
Source: Bioconductor
Version: 0.32.0
Hash: b64f82cc8788075b3d2b3c85d879fbf4
```

To reproduce:

```
git clone git@github.com:Alanocallaghan/packratty.git
cd packratty
R -e 'packrat::restore()'
```

Comment: Seems like the reason it doesn't fetch is maybe because repos aren't set. Also apparently [renv](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/index.html) is the new packrat as dictated by our omniscient rstudio overlords